# make dropdown over my datatabe

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-4

after click in my single button ,the dropdown is under my datatables !

[image]

my code :

```
<div class="dropdown">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon" aria-label="btnGroup" data-toggle="dropdown" > 
             <i class="icon icon-dots-vertical"></i>                                                              
         </button>

         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroup">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Modifier Contrat</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supprimer Contrat</a>
         </div>

</div>
```

Comment: did you try adding a z-index in css?

Comment: no i will try !

Comment: position: relative;z-index: 3; not work :(  in the div with the class dropdown-menu

Comment: You should create a minimal example in jsfiddle.

Comment: new link for the pic of the problem : https://user.oc-static.com/upload/2018/06/15/15290206774787_test.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the dropdown to stay within your modal without adjusting the z-index you can align the dropdown the the right edge of your button using the class 'dropdown-menu-right' on the 'dropdown-menu' div:

```
   <div class="dropdown">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon" aria-label="btnGroup" data-toggle="dropdown" > 
         <i class="icon icon-dots-vertical"></i>                                                              
     </button>

     <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="btnGroup">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Modifier Contrat</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supprimer Contrat</a>
     </div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer it work but when i hover the button i have this problem : http://www6.0zz0.com/2018/05/14/00/999376809.png

Comment: new link for the pic of the problem :  https://user.oc-static.com/upload/2018/06/15/15290206774787_test.png